# Does book mean leave?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, slang

I heard this sentence and wondering what does `book` mean?

> Let's book! police is comming...

I looked into a dictionary but didn't find an appropriate meaning for `book` in the sentence above but i can guess it means leaving a place.

- How commonly is used book in this way?
- Is it a informal word or formal?
- Is it old-fashioned?

Comment: Yes I think you are true and this question is already mentioned in 2012. Look at this link https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54175/what-is-the-origin-of-the-slang-term-book-meaning-leave-or-hurry

Answer (score 1):

Oxford has [*book*, as an intransitive verb, meaning "**leave suddenly**" or "**move quickly**"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/book). They list it as an American usage, and informal.

Merriam-Webster has [*book* as an intransitive verb, meaning "**leave**" or "**go**", especially "**to depart quickly**"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/book). They list it as slang.

FreeDictionary cites American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition to give [*book* as an intransitive verb meaning "**to move or travel rapidly**"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/book). This is the only one that offers any idea of etymology, of those I have found - and it is highly speculative. They suggest it is *perhaps* derived from *boogie*.

These definitions, and my experience, suggest that it's very dialect-dependent, though American cultural hegemony has probably made it more recognisable to more people around the world. I've certainly come across pop culture things where characters say "book it" to mean "run away quickly". It is also clearly very much informal. The American Heritage Dictionary version gives the example "we booked along at a nice clip", which suggests to me that it might actually have been more common once upon a time, and didn't have the connotation of *leave*, just of *move*. Now, though, the slang usage means it's not likely to be seen as old fashioned, but it is likely to be seen as very informal.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, ["Book"](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/book) *book* means to leave, usually with haste. It's not used much any more though.

It is very informal.

Comment: Some examples or an authoritative reference (or both) would make this a more informative answer for those of us who are not familiar with this idiom.

Comment: Have never heard this used in the US. Could you add a dictionary reference? I could not find one off-hand.

Comment: @StoneyB http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/book

Comment: The closest similar word I can think of would be to "scoot" or "skidaddle".

Comment: Thanks, @rebble. I've taken the liberty of editing that link into your answer.

Comment: The link you give, and the ELU link in a comment both suggest this is American, particularly New England/New York. dating back to late 60s. Nothing suggesting it is British.

Comment: It is AmE (I don't know if it's BrE or not) and it might be a little dated for slang, but I don't think it's that rare. *"Where is Joe?/He booked right after class. He must have had a [hot date](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hot_date)."*

Comment: My mistake, you are right. I think I was thinking of the word _shoot_, which is *definitely* British slang for the same thing.